# SQL removing extra commas in middle of string

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have data like this `,,a,,c,,,,,i,j,k,,m,,,,,`
I need to remove the extra commas so it looks like this `a,c,i,j,k,m`

I am using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Are you looking for an update statement? A select statement?

Comment: update, but I can work with either one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a cool trick for this:

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, ',', '><'), '<>', ''), '><', ',')
```

This gets rid of all duplicate commas, but not the ones at the beginning and end.  If you have no spaces in the values, I'm going to recommend replacing the commas with spaces and then back again, so you can use the trim functions:

```
select replace(ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(replace(col, ',', '><'), '<>', ''), '><', ','), ',', ' '))), ' ', ',')
```

I'm not sure if there is a prettier method, unless you define your own function.

Comment: wow, that was an unbelievably fast answer, and works exactly as intended. thank you!

Comment: Genius, been looking everywhere for this. Many thanks.